# update statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
update product 
set qty=100 + (select qty from product p  where p.name='abc' and p.weight='100g')
where name='abc' and weight='100g'
```

I want to add the new qty which is 100 to the existing qty of a product.
This gives me an error like this,

'You can't specify target table 'product' for update in FROM clause'

how to fix that????

Answer (score 2):

You only need to do this:

```
update product 
set qty= qty + 100
where name='abc' and weight='100g'
```